# Create an error image from a matrix containing error values (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, graphics, plot

Here's my question. I am using matlab. I have a 1024x768 matrix (obviously it maps an image) and I stored in each position the error calculated for the specific pixel (it is complicated to explain... basically for each pixel I do some calculations and store the result of these calculations in the corresponding position inside the matrix)...

I need to create a graph that is red where the error is very high and blue where the error is low, possibly creating 1024x768 image. Is it possible? And if so, how do I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using IMAGESC?

```
imagesc(yourmatrix)
```

The default `jet` colormap will give your the colors your need. Or you can change colormap to something else.

```
colormap(redbluecmap)
```